# Python - win32 - Underline

Tags: python, excel, winapi

I want to format some cells. I can select bold or italic with the following code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(template_file)
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(template_file)

wb.Worksheets(sheet).Range(range_selected).Font.Bold = 'True'
wb.Worksheets(sheet).Range(range_selected).Font.Italic = 'True'
```

But when I try to select underline it doesn't work. I have tried the following options:

```
wb.Worksheets(sheet).Range(range_selected).Font.Italic = 'True'
wb.Worksheets(sheet).Range(range_selected).Font.Underline = "xlUnderlineStyleSingle"  -- from VBA
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks,

Julen

Comment: Have you tried the [numerical values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlunderlinestyle?view=excel-pia)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [numerical values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlunderlinestyle?view=excel-pia)

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xlUnderlineStyleDouble | -4119 | Double thick underline. |
| xlUnderlineStyleDoubleAccounting | 5 | Two thin underlines placed close together. |
| xlUnderlineStyleNone | -4142 | No underlining. |
| xlUnderlineStyleSingle | 2 | Single underlining. |
| xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting | 4 | Not supported. |

E.g.,

```py
wb.Worksheets(sheet).Range(range_selected).Font.Underline = 2
```